# How to isolate ProgressEvent source?

Tags: apache-flex, event-handling

I've added a ProgressEvent listener to an instance of FileReference. At different times in the code I call both `upload()` and `load()`. How can I isolate the progression event of only the **upload method**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different objects for load and upload events, with different handlers.

Or set a flag before calling the load or upload process.